# Picking out specific individual controls out in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So what I am trying to do here is copy an html table out of clubMemebers. Paste that table into two new places, and on the second "new" table called tblBody; set its first rows visibility to hidden, change the text in the cells to '' (nothing) and make its height = 0px... basically.

The problem is probably quite an obvious one to most people... they both are linked to a single table so a change to one will make a change to them all...

How can I separate these tables to do what I need to do? I've tried to search but all I came up with is copying tables to clipboard or excel.

Here bellow is the html and the javascript I am using.

```
<div id="DivHeaderRow"></div>
<div class="gridDiv" id="gridDiv" onscroll="OnScrollDiv(this)"></div>
<div id="DivFooterRow"></div>

<table style="width: 100%;" class="MemberTbl" runat="server" id="clubMembers" >
    <tr class="Header" style="position:fixed;"></tr>
</table>
```

and the javascript:

```
function MakeStaticHeader(gridId, height, width, headerHeight, isFooter) {
    var tblHead = document.getElementById(gridId);
    var tblBody = document.getElementById(gridId);
    if (tblHead) {
        var DivHR = document.getElementById('DivHeaderRow');
        var DivMC = document.getElementById('gridDiv');
        var DivFR = document.getElementById('DivFooterRow');

        //*** Set divheaderRow Properties ****
        DivHR.style.height = headerHeight + 'px';
        DivHR.style.position = 'relative';
        DivHR.style.top = '10px';
        DivHR.style.zIndex = '10';
        DivHR.style.verticalAlign = 'top';
        DivHR.style.overflow = 'hidden';

        //*** Set divMainContent Properties ****
        DivMC.style.position = 'relative';
        DivMC.style.zIndex = '1';

        //*** Set divFooterRow Properties ****
        DivFR.style.width = (parseInt(width) - 16) + 'px';
        DivFR.style.position = 'relative';
        DivFR.style.top = -headerHeight + 'px';
        DivFR.style.verticalAlign = 'top';
        DivFR.style.paddingtop = '2px';
        DivFR.style.overflow = 'hidden';

        if (isFooter) {
            var tblfr = tbl.cloneNode(true);
            tblfr.removeChild(tblfr.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]);
            var tblBody = document.createElement('tbody');
            tblfr.style.width = '100%';
            tblfr.cellSpacing = "0";
            //*****In the case of Footer Row *******
            tblBody.appendChild(tbl.rows[tbl.rows.length - 1]);
            tblfr.appendChild(tblBody);
            DivFR.appendChild(tblfr);
        }
        //****Copy Header in divHeaderRow****
        var tblBodyRow = tblBody.rows[0];
        tblBodyRow.style.visibilty = 'hidden';
        tblBodyRow.style.height = '0px';       

        for(var i = 0, tblBodyRow; tblBodyCell = tblBodyRow.cells[i]; i++)
        {
          tblBodyCell.innerHTML = '';   
        }                

        DivHR.appendChild(tblHead.cloneNode(true));
        DivMC.appendChild(tblBody.cloneNode(true));
    }
}

function OnScrollDiv(Scrollablediv) {
    document.getElementById('DivHeaderRow').scrollLeft = Scrollablediv.scrollLeft;
    document.getElementById('DivFooterRow').scrollLeft = Scrollablediv.scrollLeft;
}

window.onload = function () {
    MakeStaticHeader('clubMembers', 100, 400, 25, false)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your problem would be fixed changing your lines:

```
var tblHead = document.getElementById(gridId);
var tblBody = document.getElementById(gridId);
```

for:

```
var tblHead = document.getElementById(gridId).cloneNode(true);
var tblBody = document.getElementById(gridId).cloneNode(true);
```

However, maybe you could try with jquery to manipulate DOM elements... Then, with something like this could be enough (see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDB2U/)):

```
tableHtml = $('#clubMembers').html();
$('#DivHeaderRow').html(tableHtml);
$('#DivHeaderRow').find("tr").first().hide();
$('#gridDiv').html(tableHtml);
```

Comment: see, I kinda knew the answer should be so simple... but when I look at the same bit of code for a while, my brain goes mush.... this seems to of worked just fine so thanks.